# T4 precompilation on build?

Tags: t4

Used MS Studio Community 2015 with SP2.

I need to recompile T4 on the build.

I do add to the project :

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
```

and

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
<TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
```

This force to recompile T4's.

But compilation have a problem - instead of using CustomToolNamespace given for specific T4 are used common RootNamespace. Result are a complete disaster.

I paly with location of CustomToolNamespace in the project file, but without positive result.

Point me where to look - still try to play with *.csproj or start look for debugging Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets?

Or simply generate 'tempalaterecompilation.bat' and run it on pre-build? I very much dislikes this way.

Answer (score 0):

I do check a Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets.
It's contain a definition for namespace

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- Unless another namespace has been specified, use the project namespace as the
  default namespace from pre-processed files. -->
  <PreprocessTemplateDefaultNamespace Condition=" $(PreprocessTemplateDefaultNamespace)=='' ">$(RootNamespace)</PreprocessTemplateDefaultNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>
```

So, RootNamespace are used intentionally.

What I need to change to get target to use a CustomToolNamespace defined for a template?

Answer (score 0):

I do find temporary solution for a problem.

There are few places from which Namespace can be picked up.

One of them - ClassNamespace​ in Content section. If this are specified given value will be used as a Namespace.

But this is work-around and I still look for solution using *.targets.